# Add OAuth authentication for HTTP request triggers

Tags: oauth-2.0, power-automate

Microsoft added a new capability - [Add OAuth authentication for HTTP request triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/oauth-authentication?tabs=classic-designer).

I've been trying to trigger the flow by using the [@azure/msal-browser](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/lib/msal-browser) package and passing the **accessToken** received in the flow in the Authorization header (i.e. Bearer {accessToken}).

But I'm getting an error:

```
code: "MisMatchingOAuthClaims"
message: "One or more claims either missing or does not match with the open authentication access control policy."
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could get the token and trigger the OAuth HTTP URL successfully!
Please follow the following steps!

- Create a flow with an HTTP trigger.
  Who can trigger the flow?: "Any user in my tenant"
- Create an app in AAD / Entra ID.
- Add Power Automate in the API permissions.
  [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGum6.png)
- Add Claims. I added all the claims for the test request. But in the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/oauth-authentication?tabs=classic-designer), just a subset is required.
  [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IcGXf.png)
- Create a secret
  [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqeCR.png)
- Fill the required parameters on the Postman Authentication tab.

Type: OAuth 2.0

Grant Type: Client Credential

Access Token URL: [https://login.microsoftonline.com/{{TenantID}}/oauth2/v2.0/token](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7B%7BTenantID%7D%7D/oauth2/v2.0/token)

Client ID: {{Client ID}}

Client Secret: {{Client Secret}}

Scope: https://service.flow.microsoft.com//.default

***pay attention to the "//" in the Scope***
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iiulZ.png)

- Get a new access token and include it as a Barear token in the header of the request you are sending to the URL of the OAuth HTTP trigger

Comment: Thank you! The tricky part was to use the double slash in //.default. i.e. https://service.flow.microsoft.com//.default

Any good explanation on why? I've didn't see it mentioned anywhere.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scopes-oidc#trailing-slash-and-default

Answer (score 0):

Was having this issue also. I was able to figure it out!

Get your token - Replace the tenantId in the URI and the clientId and clientSecret in the Body (See Image):

[Get Token from Azure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qS5Db.png)

Parse the token (See Image):

[Parse Token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkgUL.png)

Then using the token from the previous action call the HTTP Trigger replacing the URI with the URI of the HTTP Trigger (See Image):

[Send Post Request to HTTP Trigger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFVl4.png)

Comment: I'm building a Single Page Application. The clientSecret is not required for this scenario: https://auth0.com/docs/get-started/authentication-and-authorization-flow/authorization-code-flow-with-proof-key-for-code-exchange-pkce.

Comment: Also, your screenshots are duplicated.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).